# UI Tests Not Recognized in Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

After upgrading to Xcode 7.3, my UI tests were no longer recognized as test cases. The play/status gutter buttons disappeared and the test menu showed the suite folder contained "0 tests." The issue resolved in about 30 minutes after deleting derived data, cleaning the project, and re-indexing multiple times, although it was unclear which (if any) of these actions led to the fix. The issue now recurs every time the derived data is deleted, requiring another 30 minutes of cleaning, re-indexing, etc.

Is anyone else running into this problem?

All tests are properly formatted (subclasses of XCTestCase, prepended with "test" keyword) and had been running without issue for weeks in Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Have you rebooted since upgrading Xcode? Have you looked in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app for error messages involving Xcode?

Comment: @bneely Yes, I've rebooted since upgrading. There are several Xcode error messages in Console, but all are related to the derived data issue that caused me to delete the cache.

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you create a new empty project in Xcode which uses UI tests? If your project exists in a repository, can you reproduce it if you check out/clone a clean copy? How about trying the same Xcode project on another machine?

Comment: @bneely A coworker ran into the same problem on another machine with a clean copy of the project, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue in a new project. This may be project specific. In any case, I've found two workarounds: 1) Running the test suite from the command line executes without issue and causes Xcode to recognize the tests again. 2) For individual tests, removing a file from the UITest target and adding it back causes it to be recognized as a test.

Comment: The steps I might take next are: binary-search through the revisions and find when the corrupting change was introduced, and manage the project file from that point (e.g. revert and reapply any necessary changes); determine if re-creating the project will ultimately take less time and frustration than continuing to work around the issue; consider filing a bug with Apple if you're willing to send them enough resources from your project for them to reproduce and debug.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how large is the project in terms of source and resource files, and build targets?

Comment: @bneely The project is enormous, so large that it would take a while to get an accurate count on source files, etc. I'm sticking with the workarounds for now and waiting to see if the issue recurs enough to warrant further action. Thanks for all of your help with this!

Comment: One thing you can try is: 1. delete derived data, 2. wait for indexing to finish, 3. remove all testcase files from the target (use Xcode's "Target Membership" on the right side panel), 4. add testcase files back one by one until you hit the problem.

Comment: Another thing that might have fixed the problem for me was to remove the imports at the top of XCTestCase subclasses, including import XCTest, Foundation, UIKit, whatever.